# A subgroup of the symmetric group of a homogeneous principal $G-$set E

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions

Let $G$ be a group and $E$ a homogeneous principal $G-$set; let $\Gamma$ denote the automorphism group of $G$. Let $\mathfrak{S}_{E}$ denote the symmetric group of $E$ and

$$A=\{f\in\mathfrak{S}_{E}\ |\ (\exists\gamma)(\gamma\in\Gamma\land(\forall g)(\forall b)(g\in G\land b\in E\implies f(g.b)=\gamma(g).f(b))\}.$$

**Claim.** Let $f\in A$. Then $\gamma\in\Gamma$ is unique.

**Question:** Why is it unique?

Any hints will be appreciated.

**My attempt:** (the goal is to eventually show that $A\leq\mathfrak{S}_{E}$ and that there exists a homomorphism $p:A\rightarrow\Gamma$)

Since $E$ is a homogeneous principal $G-$set, there exists an $x\in E$ such that the orbital mapping $g\mapsto g.x$ defined by $x$ is a $G-$isomorphism of $G$ onto $E$. Now, I understand that, given $f\in A$, I have to show that $\gamma=\delta$ for any $\delta\in\Gamma$ such that 
$$(\forall g)(\forall b)(g\in G\land b\in E\implies f(g.b)=\delta(g).f(b)).$$
Suppose the existence of a $\delta\in\Gamma$ satisfying the above property. We have that, for every $g\in G$,
$$\gamma(g).f(x)=f(g.x)=\delta(g).f(x);$$ 
i.e., $\gamma(g).f(x)=\delta(g).f(x)$. But I'm not sure how to proceed from this point.

**EDIT: (Solved)**

$g\in G$ implies $g=\delta^{-1}(\alpha)$ and $g=\delta^{-1}(\beta)$ for some $\alpha,\beta\in G$:
$$\alpha.x=\delta(\delta^{-1}(\alpha)).f(f^{-1}(x))=\delta(g).f(f^{-1}(x))=f(g.f^{-1}(x)),$$
$$f(g.f^{-1}(x))=\gamma(g).f(f^{-1}(x))=\gamma(\gamma^{-1}(\beta)).f(f^{-1}(x))=\beta.x;$$
therefore, $\alpha=\beta$. Hence, $\delta(g)=\alpha=\beta=\gamma(g)$.